# HttpClient returns unsupported media type error when I send json object along with IFormFile in .NET 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient, iformfile

I have been struggling for the past three days trying to send serialized json of a complex type (DTO object called `fileItem`) and `IFormFile` type named as file to one of my API which accepts two inputs, a `FileItem` object and `IFormFile` object.

But I keep getting an error "Unsupported Media Type". Note that when I send only file or only object then to API end point by updating the endpoint to accept either file only or complexType only, then it works fine, but if I am sending both together, then I get that "Unsupported Media Type" error which is already available in the request I am sending

Please guide me in a proper direction your help will be really appreciated.

ASP.NET MVC web app

```
public async Task<string> SaveFiles(FileItem _fileItem2, IFormFile _file)
{
    using (var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var fileItem = new StringContent(
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(_fileItem2), Encoding.UTF8, Application.Json);
        multipartFormContent.Add(fileItem, "fileItem");

        // Add the file
        var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(_file.OpenReadStream());
        fileStreamContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(_file.ContentType);
        multipartFormContent.Add(fileStreamContent, name: "file", _file.FileName);

        // Method 1 : this method returns Unsupported media type, but if file is removed then it works fine.
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/Upload/SaveFileWithData", multipartFormContent);

        // Method 2 : this method also returns Unsupported media type, but if file is removed then it works fine.
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/Upload/SaveFileWithData");
        request.Content = multipartFormContent;
        var responsemsg = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        responsemsg.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await responsemsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the .NET 6.0 Web API (above request we send to this api)

```
[HttpPost()]
[Route("SaveFileWithData")]
public async Task<string> SaveFileWithData(FileItem? fileItem, IFormFile? file)
{
    int i = 2;
    return "fileSavedSuccessfully";
}
```

Comment: Ehhm, would encoding the data maybe be an option?

Comment: while making the string content data is already getting encoded with UTF-8

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I should have been more clear. How about base64?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class FileItem
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> SaveFiles(FileItem _fileItem2, IFormFile _file)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7241/");
    using (var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {

        multipartFormContent.Add(new StringContent(_fileItem2.FileName), "FileName");
        multipartFormContent.Add(new StringContent(_fileItem2.Type), "Type");

        var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(_file.OpenReadStream());
        
        multipartFormContent.Add(fileStreamContent, name: "file", _file.FileName);

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/Upload/SaveFileWithData", multipartFormContent);

        //...
    }
}
```

Web APi:

```
[HttpPost()]
[Route("SaveFileWithData")]
public async Task<string> SaveFileWithData([FromForm]FileItem? fileItem, [FromForm] IFormFile? file)
{
    int i = 2;
    return "fileSavedSuccessfully";
}
```

**Note:**  **non-nullable property must be required** in ASP.NET 6, be sure you post all the properties by HttpClient, otherwise you will receive 400 Bad Request.

If you do not want all the property required, you can check the reference below:https://stackoverflow.com/a/71701358/11398810

Comment: Dear Rena, thank you very much for your time and efforts this i will try and get back but one thing is strange that do i need to add each property of my complex type to multipartformcontent, can't we send the whole object at once beause it may have 20plus properties adding each property individually does not seems a right approach but can be a workaround. anyway thanks for your time i can atleast proceed to achieve target results which is appretiable from your good self.